# Problema con Plugin WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, mercadopago, woocommerce

Desde que actualizamos el pluging estamos recibiendo un error al activarlo, les dejo los datos:

- **Email Mercado Pago**:   mercadolibre@ofit.com.ar
- **Problema**;

  > Al activar el plugin de MercadoPago WooCommerce, obtenemos el error HTTP ERROR 500 y queda toda nuestra web caida

  - Version of WooCommerce;  3.4.4
  - Module version  3.0.17

Si alguien me puede ayudar le estoy agradecido.

Comment: Bienvenido..Javier., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc. Es importante que sepas que el sitio no da soporte a la compañía que haces referencia en tu pregunta  saludos!

Comment: Hola Javier, de forma muy cortés te pregunto ¿Para qué nos dejáis el email de mercadolibre? ¿Esperáis que contactemos con ellos para saber que ha pasado con su plugin?

Comment: Hola Jorge, no perdon, quisiera saber de que forma puedo contactar con el soporte de ellos, pense que en este sitio tambien contestaban ellos

Comment: no hay problema @JavierCessario es una confusión común; no somos soporte oficial de ellos o de algún otro te recomiendo hacer el [tour] para que te familiarices mas con el sitio

Comment: Además por seguridad te aconsejo quitar la cuenta de correo que pusiste

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente tenga que ver con un conflicto de versiones entre el plugin y alguna otra pieza de software.

El plugin que causa el error tiene los siguientes requerimientos:

**Versión de WordPress: 4.9.7 o superior**

**Probado hasta: 4.9.8**

**Versión de PHP: 5.6 o superior**

Revisa que tanto la versión de PHP del servidor como tu versión de WordPress cumplan los requisitos para solucionarlo.

[Fuente](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/)